# Parsing an iCal file to show the next event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, icalendar

I wanted to ask if there was a way to parse an iCalendar file and then show the latest event in JavaScript/node.js?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may start with the existing libs first. e.g. https://github.com/DHTMLX/scheduler
You can load the ical files using the lib and implement your logic from there.

However if you decide to implement your own logic, you need to take note that ical files can be a bit complicated. Other systems can use the ical files to create, update or delete an event, the event can be one time only or recurring. You need to consider all these scenarios.

Comment: events can also have a modification in another VEVENT, so one has to read the whole file to check one has all the details.   ALSO RRULES can be very complex, easy to make a mistake calculating next date.

Comment: Thanks for all the help man. I voted but my reputation is too low for it to count. Honestly, this is exactly what I needed. I didn't even realise it. Thanks.